# OpenCV perspective transform in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to rectify an image in python. I have a Homography H (from a rotation matrix that rotates around the x, y and z axis) that looks like this for example:
        [[  9.95671447e-01   7.83610423e-02   7.47993630e+02]
         [ -7.69292630e-02   9.96586377e-01  -4.48354859e+02]
         [ -3.48494755e-06   1.73615469e-06   9.98300856e-01]]

I thought I could do this woth cv2.perspectiveTransform() but I cant't get it to work. This is the code I use:

```
   # warp image
   img_cv2 = cv2.imread('surf.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
   # strange output but it does something:
   dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(img_cv2,H)
```

But I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\directory structure\python_files\Rectification\rectify.py", line 82, in <module>
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(img_cv2,H)
    error: C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp:1916: error: (-215) scn + 1 == m.cols && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F)`</pre>
```

Can anybody see what is going wrong?

Comment: Accept an answer, thus it appears as solved and would help others who come with this same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source and destination image must be floating point data.

> cv2.perspectiveTransform(src, m[, dst]) → dst
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - src – input two-channel or three-channel floating-point array; each element is a 2D/3D vector to be transformed.
> - dst – output array of the same size and type as src.
> - m – 3x3 or 4x4 floating-point transformation matrix.

Refer:http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=perspectivetransform#cv2.perspectiveTransform

So convert the 8U image to the appropriate datatype.

Comment: That's what can be found from your reference: "The function transforms a sparse set of 2D or 3D vectors" - this function is not about transforming images, look at @AldurDisciple answer

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is `cv2.warpPerspective` (see documentation [(link)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#cv2.warpPerspective)), not `cv2.perspectiveTransform`.

Answer (score 0):

It says the image should be `np.float32` or `np.float64`.

So convert the image first by `img_cv2 = np.float32(img_cv2)`.

Then apply the `cv2.perspectiveTransform()` and `cv2.warpPerspective()`

Check **[this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#perspective-transformation)** for demo